# Copy key to server in powershell?

Tags: ssh, powershell

I want to copy an `id_rsa.pub` key to a server by SSH. This [link](https://superuser.com/a/1801553) mentions how to do just that but it's not working when I enter in the correct credentials for the SSH login ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Command to copy client public key to Windows OpenSSH SFTP/SSH server authorized keys file](https://superuser.com/questions/1451241/command-to-copy-client-public-key-to-windows-openssh-sftp-ssh-server-authorized). I would suggest you look at the accepted answer.

Comment: I linked to the command in question in powershell and that link was the exact link which you supplied. 

Comment: I know, but the accepted answer was written by Martin Prikryl and you won't anyone more knowledgeable than him on our site,

Comment: I can't comment to him as to why that command is not working for me; therefore how can I solve this ?

Comment: Read his answer thoroughly an try it out first.